# Notepad++ Find and Replace with Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

This is my coding:

```
alpha = ["first", 55, 28]
beta  = ["second", 89, 09]
gamma = ["third", 99, 40]
```

And this is my intended outcome:

```
first", 55, 28]
second", 89, 09]
third", 99, 40]
```

I've tried replace the regex of `^.*?"` with empty. But why I get this instead?:

```
, 55, 28]
, 89, 09]
, 99, 40]
```

Comment: it should work..can you try using `^[^"]*"`..

Comment: have you enabled multiline mode (_if there is any_)?

Comment: In addition to what @rock321987 is saying, here's a demo: https://regex101.com/r/xO6nF7/2 (plus, enable multiline mode!)

Comment: Thanks Rock and Jan for prompt reply. I think the regex provided by Rock do match the pattern I willing to replace. But once I click on "Replace All" button in the Notepad++. It seem like doing replace after replace, until all the matching pattern are gone.

Comment: Are you sure your regex doesn't work? It behaves as if you left out the question mark

Comment: I'm closing this as a typo. Your regex works: see [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/l1c3gFfBJ1)

Comment: There is a strange issue. If we try to `find` with this regex, then it's working fine. But If we try to `replace` it, then it's replacing wrong content.

Comment: @Bohemian It takes some finessing to make the regex _work_, even after getting the correct regex.

Comment: @tim do you agree that `^.*?"` works?

Comment: @Bohemian Nope, that won't work, because if you do a replace all you end up with junk (I just tested on his actual data).  Disclaimer: The regex is logically correct, but the way Notepad++ operates makes it trickier than you might think.

Comment: @tim it *won't* work, or you've tried it and it *doesn't* work?

Comment: @Bohemian I just tried it, and it didn't work.

Comment: @Bohemian it does work. it just works a bit too much [you see](http://rubular.com/r/vsc2lnWRUb). that's what he meant by "It seem like doing replace after replace, until all the matching pattern are gone."

Comment: @Bohemian You could have closed this as a duplicate, but it's not really off topic if you decide that it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @Bohemian did you not read my comment. it works. but not 100%. 200%. it removes the next found match too. which in turn causes the OP to not get what he wants as a result. a good regex would stop after the first match. yours goes beyond that. the problem is that OP wants to use it in replace in notepad++. your regex is right for searching, no doubt. but for automated replace, it fails as it doesn't stop at right time.

Comment: @mri I actually think there's a bug in notepad++. If you replace `^.*?"` with `X` (ie *something*) it works as expected, but if you replace with blank, it doesn't work. I suspect there's a bug where the match pointer is incorrectly set after replacing with blank.

Comment: @Tim I reopened, but I see my previous comment

Comment: @Bohemian yes, you could call it a bug, or maybe a feature. it appears notepad++ continues to process the regex and replacing until no matches are found. it seems necessary if you're going to do it for all the results in a page. although not sure if it's necessary to do it again for the same page. maybe they added it as a feature so user doesn't have to worry about recurring patterns. who know?

Comment: @rock321987 Just for your information - multiline mode is enabled automatically in Notepad++. You can only turn it off by using inline modifier `(?-m)`

Comment: After the first replace, the cursor is still at the start of the line, thus the ^-anchor is matched again in the next iteration. I don't know if this is wanted, but at least it is consistent behaviour.

Comment: @SebastianProske thanks for clarification..i do not use notepad++

Comment: `Replace` is a single atomic operation. Are you deciding whether to replace or not, and skip to next if not ? Just do a find next, then replace that one. Otherwise do a replace all, which is not an atomic operation. In **replace-all**, it's like a global flag.  A new string is created that appends each time from the last match position to the new match position with minus/add the replacement text. The original string is unchanged so the next start position pointer is 1 + the end of the last match.

Comment: The content you try to erase has a fixed width. I would solve this using alt+clic to select the area and erase.

Comment: @seb that's not how regex replace works in every other tool/language (AFAIK), which don't "match again" at start of input. The start of input match is a one-time concept. Notepad++ seems to reset everything after every replacement like it's a new input. This behaviour has nothing to do with multiline mode - setting or not setting the flag has no effect on this behaviour.

Comment: @Bohemian Just to clearify: By consistent i meant consistent for Notepad++, not regarding any other tool - so you will meet the same behaviour for any kind of empty-replacement that includes a `^` in the search pattern. My first comment was totally unrelated to the second one and aimed towards rock.

Answer (score 9):

Find and replace with
`^.*?\["`

**Input**

```
alpha = ["first", 55, 28]
beta  = ["second", 89, 09]
gamma = ["third", 99, 40]
```

**Result**

```
first", 55, 28]
second", 89, 09]
third", 99, 40]
```

---

The problem with `^.*?"` is that it's replacing all the content one by one

1. You're starting with this content

   ```
   alpha = ["first", 55, 28]
   beta  = ["second", 89, 09]
   gamma = ["third", 99, 40]
   ```
2. After first replace (as expected), the content becomes this,

   ```
   first", 55, 28]
   beta  = ["second", 89, 09]
   gamma = ["third", 99, 40]
   ```
3. Now, in the next replace, the cursor is still at the start of the line. Notice that there is one more double quote `"` in this line (just after the text `first`), thus the RegEx is matched again and so it will again replace everything before
   the first double quote

   ```
   , 55, 28]
   beta  = ["second", 89, 09]
   gamma = ["third", 99, 40]
   ```
4. When you continue in this manner, you'll get the output as:

   ```
   , 55, 28]
   , 89, 09]
   , 99, 40]
   ```

And so use `^.*?\["` instead of `^.*?"`

---

**EDIT**

If there are any chances that you have arrays inside your parent array, then you can use `^.*?\=\s*\[\s*"`.
This regex will also deal with whitespace character.

**Input**

```
alpha = ["first", 55, 28]
beta  =   ["second", 89, 09]
gamma =      ["third", 99, 40]
delta = ["fourth", ["55"], 28]
```

**After replace**

```
first", 55, 28]
second", 89, 09]
third", 99, 40]
fourth", ["55"], 28]
```

Comment: Explanation is correct, but the solution is not, try it against `alpha = ["first", ["55"], 28]`. It might not be something OP will have in the input, but the point is that you just have to match the whole line to be able to use such a replacement with Replace all.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I understand, there may be many cases like this, though I've only dealt with the code that OP have supplied. Anyways, thanks for pointing it out, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Use this regex:

```
^[^"]*"(.*)$
```

The quantity in parenthesis is called a *capture group*, because its contents will be captured for each line in your file for which the replace operation is run.  You want to retain this captured material, so use a replacement of `\1` in the dialog box.

Here is a screen capture of how to use it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you could try this `.*=\s?\[`. of course all setting as @TimBiegeleisen showed.